# How to include special character (e.g. '=') as part of variable value in docker-compose .env file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

As per [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), environment variables in .env file expected to be in in key-val format as `VAR=VAL` which works fine for sample like `foo=bar` but no mention of unavoidable special characters e.g. '=', which may confuse for `key-val` separator OR `space` both part of valid db connection string as in:

secrets.env file:

```
 connectionString=Data Source=some-server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=uid;Password=secretpassword
```

which is referred in docker-compose.debug.yaml file content as:

```
services:
  some-service:
    container_name: "service-name"
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Which is further used to transform into `docker-compose.yaml` as shown complete flow below:

[image]

So the question is - how do you include connection string which has `=` and `Spaces` as part of value ?

**Need** - We have few  micro-services within VS solution and looking forward to avoid repetition of same connection strings otherwise needs in service spec of `docker-compose.yaml'

**Tried** including values in single/double quote but post transformation whatever after `=` is treated as value including quotes just similar like kubernets yaml file convention

Comment: can you post your current env file?

Comment: conString=`Data Source=some-server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=uid;Password=secretpassword`

Comment: the value of `echo $conString` is like this `Data Source=some-server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=uid;Password=secretpassword` , is this correct ?

Comment: most of unix platform will accept single or double quote. So you may try KEY="VAL".  Not for window container.

Comment: @vsatkh,  key="val" combination in .env file transform into key='"val"' but 
key : "val" is fine inside docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 2):

I ran a test without any issues:

```
$ cat .env
ENV=default
USER_NAME=test2
SPECIAL=field=with=equals;and;semi-colons

$ cat docker-compose.env.yml
version: '2'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    command: env
    environment:
      - SPECIAL

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.env.yml up
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_test_1_55eac1c3767c ... done
Attaching to test_test_1_d7787ac5bfc0
test_1_d7787ac5bfc0 | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
test_1_d7787ac5bfc0 | HOSTNAME=d249a16a8e09
test_1_d7787ac5bfc0 | SPECIAL=field=with=equals;and;semi-colons
test_1_d7787ac5bfc0 | HOME=/root
test_test_1_d7787ac5bfc0 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Thanks @BMitch but would appreciate scenario including variable .env file included in `some-compose.yaml` file preferably with `spaces` included. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @anilr from my answer above, you can see a [mcve], including every file needed, commands run, and output shown, to easily reproduce the solution. If you can do the same to show the problem you are encountering, that would help.

Comment: Does this work if you wrap SPECIAL in double quotes?

Comment: @BrandonRos if you have a question, use the "ask a question" link.